# records missing when I loop though xml php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Apologies if this is a duplicate, I see other similar problems, but I cant get mine to work.

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<quizzes>
<quiz>
<title>Arithmetic quiz</title>
<description>
<text>Seeing how mathematical quiz works</text>
</description>

<grading>
<range start="0" end="49">
<grade>F</grade>
<rank/>
</range>
<range start="50" end="60">
<grade>D</grade>
<rank/>
</range>
<range start="60" end="69">
<grade>C</grade>
<rank/>
</range>
<range start="70" end="79">
<grade>B</grade>
<rank/>
</range>
<range start="80" end="100">
<grade>A</grade>
<rank/>
</range>
</grading>

<question type="">
<text>Select the correct value for the common difference:2,6,10,14,18,22</text>
<option>
<text>26</text>
<score>5</score>
<explanation>
<text>Correct!</text>
</explanation>
</option>

<option>
<text>18</text>
<score>0</score>
<explanation>
<text>Incorrect!</text>
</explanation>
</option>

<option>
<text>10</text>
<score>0</score>
<explanation>
<text>Incorrect!</text>
</explanation>
</option>
</question>

</quiz>
</quizzes>
```

I would to be able to loop through and get the 'score' element, but I am not getting anything other than 'quizzes' echo'ed out.

My code looks like this:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("maths.xml");
echo $xml->getName() . "<br>";

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
   {
   echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br>";
   }
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? I think I am not traversing the XML tree deep enough but I dont know how to accomplish this.

Comment: Well, obviously you just get quiz when you are foreach'ing over the children of the root element only. You are not even attempting to get at the score.

Comment: @Gordon  Thanks, I suspected it was something like this. I am a bit of a noob so I was even sure what to google.

Comment: Check out the [basic usage samples for SimpleXML in the PHP Manual](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Comment: Derp. Question got closed as soon as I typed the answer. Anyway, I'll post it as a comment: http://codepad.org/gCGleRi0 :P

Comment: @AmalMurali you can prevent that by searching for dupes before putting effort into answering what was answered before. It also helps to keep the site clean. You got 3k now, so you can closevote. Use that privilege.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`xpath()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) for that:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file('math.xml');
var_dump($xml->xpath('//score'));
```

`//score` will select all `<score>` elements regardless of their position in the xml tree. I've google a beginners article about simple xml for you: [link](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-parse-xml-with-php5)

An alternative would be to use [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('math.xml');

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('score') as $element) {
    echo $element->nodeValue;
}
```

Tutorial: [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-xmldomphp/)